# .htaccess code to deny folder browsing

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-autoindex

Can you please tell me how to deny folder browsing using .htaccess file

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Options -Indexes
```

Answer (score -2):

```
order allow deny
deny from all
allow from 192.126.12.199
```

Comment: Some formatting would be good and some explanation + context. Plus allowing from a specific IP was not part of the OPs question.